# Remove Icon Arrow if Category haven't Sub-category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, icons, categories

`enter code here`Does any one can advice me how to remove the icon for main category havent's sub-categories.
I have pass to show sub-categories under main category.

Here is my code:
[enter image description here][1]

My view:

[blade View][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbDuB.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieAqL.png

My Update with code

```
    public static function showCategories($categories, $parent_id = 0)
{
  $class  ='';
  $html = ""; //init
  $flag = false;
           foreach ($categories as $row) {
              if ($row['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
                 //we have a category
                 $link =self::linkCategory($row['category_id'],$row['name']);
                 $html .= '<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
                                          <li>
                                          <div class="link accordion-title"><a href="'.$link.'">'.$row['name'].'</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>';
                                          $html .= "<ul class='submenu'>";
                 foreach ($categories as $subcat) {

                       $link =self::linkCategory($subcat['category_id'],$subcat['name']);
                       if ($subcat['parent_id'] ==$row['category_id']){
                          //we have a subcategory
                          $html .= '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$subcat['name'].'</a></li>';
                       }
                 }
                       $html .= "</ul>";
                     $html .= "</li>";
                 $html .= "</ul>";
              }
     }      
     return $html;
```

//call it blade
$menu = URL::showCategories($itemCategory);

Comment: Images of code are extremely hard to read and troubleshoot. Please add the code here as text.

Comment: Why are you building your own HTML in the controller? You should be passing that to a blade file.

Answer (score 0):

first of all its a bad practice that you use HTML in control, you have to use HTML only in blade sec you can do that by making the relation between categories and itself to get the sub cat to every cat then if your blade while you are looping it u can easily use Count() to get number of sub cat if it bigger than 0
add icon if don't add it

```
@if(Count($cat->sub) > 0) 
    <i class="icon-class">
 @endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).